# why Ajax not properly work on live server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

```js
function couponCal() {
  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType:'json',
    url:"{{ url('coupon/calculation') }}",
    success: function (data) {
      var d = $('.cart-ship-charge span').empty();

      if (data.total) {
        $('#couponCal').html(
          `<tr>
            <th>
              <div class="cart-sub-total">
                Subtotal<span class="inner-left-md">$ ${data.subtotal}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="cart-grand-total">
                Grand Total<span class="inner-left-md">$ ${data.total}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="cart-ship-charge">
                Ship Charge<span class="inner-left-md">$ ${data.ship_charge}</span>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>`
        )
      } else {
        $('#couponCal').html(
          `<tr>
            <th>
              <div class="cart-sub-total">
                Subtotal<span class="inner-left-md">$ ${data.subtotal}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="cart-sub-total">
                Coupon Name<span class="inner-left-md">$ ${data.coupon_name}</span>
                <button type="submit" onclick="couponRemove()"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </div>
              <div class="cart-sub-total">
                Discount Amount<span class="inner-left-md">$ ${data.discount_amount}</span>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="cart-ship-charge">
                Ship Charge<span class="inner-left-md">$ ${data.ship_charge}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="cart-grand-total">
                Grand Total<span class="inner-left-md">$ ${data.Grand_total}</span>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>`
        )
      }
    }
  });
}

couponCal();

$(document).on('click', '#ship_btn', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  couponCal();
  $('#proceedCheck').show();
});
```

couponCal() did not work properly. what can I do?

Comment: "did not work properly" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: not showing data inside couponCal function where data like shipcharge , subtotal, total amount showing without reloading page

Comment: add an error callback and check if it's giving you any error.

Comment: We can't debug server errors for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue in my production.

in my case the issue was https, my server only accepted https requests if not redirected. so i updated my appserviceprovider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Paginator::useBootstrap();
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```